# Install rpm and put file into symbolic link directory

Tags: linux, symlink, rpm, cp, rhel6

I have made an `rpm` package that install a program and one of the folders it needs to copy a file to is a `symbolic link` since the program the symbolic link is pointing to may change over time so it is easier to maintain the building of the `rpm` package by copying the file to the `symbolic link` rather then to the hard coded path. However, I get the error

```
cp: cannot overwrite directory with non-directory
```

when the `rpm` package tried to copy the file to the symbolic link folder. Why does this happen, and is there anything I can do to work around this error other then making the files to be copied to the folder the `symbolic link` points to? I am running `RHEL 6.6` as of note.

Comment: What does the `cp` line that is failing look like exactly? Does it have a trailing slash on the target?

Comment: It says can not overwrite directory `/opt/tomcat/bin with /foo/opt/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh`

Comment: I was asking about the line in the spec file not the error.

Comment: oh, i am not sure as I am using a make file to generate and it cleans the spec file but i just have it do a cp with no options at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error generally means something like you having told cp to treat the target as a normal file (the `-T` argument).

```
$ ls -lR
.:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  6 09:46 dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb  6 09:45 file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3 Feb  6 09:45 symdir -> dir

./dir:
total 0
$ cp -T file symdir
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `symdir' with non-directory
$ ls -lR
.:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  6 09:46 dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb  6 09:45 file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3 Feb  6 09:45 symdir -> dir

./dir:
total 0
$ cp file symdir
$ ls -lR
.:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  6 09:46 dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Feb  6 09:45 file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    3 Feb  6 09:45 symdir -> dir

./dir:
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb  6 09:46 file
```